# Why starts xsd execution in msbuild Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio, msbuild, xsd

I have the following execution task in my msbuild.xml

```
<Target Name="XSD">
  <ItemGroup>
    <XSDEXE Include="lib\xsd\xsd.exe" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Exec Command="$(XSDEXE) path2myXSD\mySpecial.xsd /o:outPutPath /c /n:mySpecialNamespace" />
</Target>
```

If I execute this with

```
MSBuild.exe msbuild.xml /target:XSD
```

the Visual Studio starts with the xsd in design mode.

WHY ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $(XSDEXE) references a property rather than an ItemGroup, so when you execute that task, you're passing this command line:

```
path2myXSD\mySpecial.xsd /o:outPutPath /c /n:mySpecialNamespace
```

To resolve this, change the ItemGroup to a PropertyGroup like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <XSDEXE>lib\xsd\xsd.exe</XSDEXE>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For extra credit, make a diagnostic log allowing you to quickly diagnose the problem.

```
msbuild.exe <your arguments> /fl5 /flp5:Verbosity=diag;logfile=msbuild.log
```